# Objective-C Class Not Found In Swift Bridging Header

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cordova, bridging-header

I am updating our Cordova framework and I am stuck on getting a particular Objective-C plugin class to work.

In my old (un-updated) project everything works just fine. I have a BridgingHeader.h file, its properly referenced in the build settings. However in my new updated project it can no longer find only one Objective-C class (`PushPlugin.m`).

What's strange is its finding all other Objective-C classes just fine, its just the `PushPlugin.m` it can't find.

Here is my BridgingHeader:

```
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <Parse/PFObject.h>
#import <Parse/PFSubclassing.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <objc/message.h>
#import "GPUImage.h"
#import "PushPlugin.h" // This one is not found
#import "CDVParsePlugin.h"
```

And when I try to use `PushPlugin` I get not found error:

```
//AppDelegate.swift

        let pushHander:PushPlugin = getCommandInstance("PushPlugin") as! PushPlugin
        // ERROR: PushPlugin not found
```

To be extra certain, the `PushPlugin` file is referenced in the `Compile Sources`. And my `BridgingHeader` is properly referenced in the build settings.

Do you have any idea why one specific Objective-C class is not being found?

**Update**

So to be clear, there is no error reporting the BridgingHeader file. Its only when I try to use the PushPlugin that I encounter the error (meaning its not importing properly).

As suggested I ran a commandline build I got a build failed with these reasons:

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  CompileSwift normal arm64
> /Users/user/Desktop/mobile-cordova-upgrade/app/platforms/ios/App/Classes/AppDelegate.swift
>
> CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
>
> (2 failures)

Comment: Build with xcodebuild (from the command line) and then look for the compiler call that fails.  It will have the full list of import locations (look for `-I`)

Comment: I ran a command line build but it didn't give any relevant information that I could discern.

Comment: Can you add a .m (or edit one) -- add an #import `"PushPlugin.h"` to it and try to compile it.

Comment: Ok I found the issue and it was very obscure. There was another Bridging header with the same name but at the wrong path. The build settings was identifying the bridging header path I THOUGHT was correct (based on the group setup in my project). But because Groups aren't actual folders I was mistaking the path for correct when it wasn't. So it turns out there WAS another bridging header and the path was wrong. Silly me :/. Thanks for the help though it got me looking in the right direction.